# Finding table and package references in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a list of tables and a list of packages. I need to come up with the below two lists

- What are the packages that uses the given set of tables
- List of tables that are referenced by each of the given package

The packages uses dynamic sql, hence I may not be able to depend only on dba_reference table.
The other way I could think of is using a LIKE clause against the dba_source table. But, I will have to write a OR condition for each of the tables that I need (or of course a function or procedure which can loop through each table)

Is there any better way of doing this?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit: rephrasing the question -**

I have a package which select/inserts/updates several tables. This has dynamic sql. One example is provided below.

I want to identify all the tables referred in this package. What is the best way to achieve this?

In the below example I want to capture both table1 and table2.

```
if flag = 'Y'
then final_sql := 'insert into table1 (...)';
else final_sql := 'insert into table2 (...)';
end if;
execute immediate final_sql;
```

Comment: you want to find a reference table name that is changing ?

Comment: The stored procedures in the package has lot of IF conditions which form the SQL dynamically. Some of the tables may not be used in some business scenarios. I want to capture all the tables used. Not sure if this kind of references are maintained in dba_reference table.

Comment: i guess it will check it  run `select * from User_Dependencies where type='TABLE' and name in('TAB1','TAB2')` 
and tell me what is the result

Comment: This works as you expected. However, there is one more scenario in my case. At few places, we are forming the SQL as a string and later passing it to some other package for execution. I can get such details from dba_source table, but not from dba_dependencies

Comment: why don't you use a join between the both table ? I am not sure what is your scenario but a simple ex: `select * from User_Dependencies  where name exists (select trim(TEXT) from user_source where TEXT like '%TAB1%`'

Comment: Yes, that works. I can directly get it from user_source without using the user_dependencies table. However, I have over 1000 tables. So, I need 1000 OR conditions. I was checking if there is a better way. That was my original question.

Comment: ok so your main question your a calling a table in a package however its quoted , you want to know if you can catch it as a reference right ? I Like this question, please edit your question in such manner and ill add a bounty for your question. Btw can you show me a simple example how your quoting and executing it

Comment: Rephrased the question. Let me know if you need more details on this.

Answer (score 0):

For systems using a lot of dynamic SQL I suggest two approaches.

First one is to apply strict coding standards so you know what to look for and can then reliably parse out the table names from the rest of the code. I mean, always have the table same string written to  a known variable name, and search for that variable.

This is not always easy to do, especially if you have mountains of code that do not follow the standard. It only takes a couple of folk to not adhere to the standard and it all falls down. However it can be made to work, but probably never going to be 100% reliable.

Another approach is to write test scripts that exercise the whole code base and logic paths. Write them in such a way that they log the procedure name. Enable SQL Trace and capture the trace files from the tests. With clever scripting you should be able to tie the trace to the procedure. This will give you the "raw" SQL, which you can then grep for matches with you list of tables. You might be able to get the same info by harvesting V$SQL tying to V$SESSION.

This is an old school way of doing this, but one that I have used and works.

On one of the largest systems I worked on I wrote a CRUD parser which tokenised the code and produced a CRUD matrix by source file and table access. For dynamic SQL we processed SQL Trace/tkprof files.

If the code has good amount of debugging which dumps out these the table names you could again run the test scripts and harvest the debug logs.

Comment: As you mentioned, the first method is not reliable. Second method depends on how well I handle all the logical conditions. This is a challenge in itself in case of large applications. I guess another way to do it is, get all the table names and scan them against all the packages in the user_source table using a script.